# Accessing a different folder using classloader

Tags: java, classloader

```
 URL root = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(packageName.replace(".", "/"));
```

i use the above statement to access .class files given a package name. But in some cases i need to access the files from **\build\test\classes** instead of **\build\classes**. How do i modify the above statement?

Comment: you need to change your runtime classpath to include test resources, java code remains the same

Comment: I would like to do it in code since both cases are possible.

Comment: The class loader can't load something that is not in its classpath.

Comment: Are you using Maven?  Maven puts test/classes and test/resources into the class path during testing.  Otherwise, you'll have to configure your system through your IDE or Ant to either set the right classpath during tests.

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems with your classpath.
`${project}/build/test/classes` and `${project}/build/classes` folders suggest that you have either used Ant to compile your code, or checked **"Allow output folders for source folders"** option in Eclipse's "New Java Project" dialog.

You should configure you project to compile all source files into the same output folder, in your case `/build/classes`.

If you use classloader to load a resource the path you give it **is not absolute to entire filesystem** even if it starts with `/`.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/some/resource");
```

This actually means find this file `${project}/build/classes/some/resource`.
And in order to get that resource at the target location the easiest way is to place it in `${project}/src/some/resource`.

Although you should consider using Maven and m2eclipse if your using Eclipse.